# How to write this Oracle SQL subquery in JPA?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am having problem in writing the following Oracle SQL query in JPA.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM bt_backup_main_status ORDER BY dates DESC) WHERE   
ROWNUM <= 5 AND flag = 1
```

The logic is really simple. It selects top 5 latest dates rows whose flag is 1.

So now i want to write this query in JPA. I have tried the following code.

```
String query = "SELECT i FROM (SELECT q FROM BtBackupMainStatus q ORDER BY q.dates DESC) i
                WHERE ROWNUM <= :rownum AND i.flag = :flag";
Query q = em.createQuery(query);
q.setParameter("rownum", 5);
q.setParameter("flag", 1);*/
List<BtBackupMainStatus> result = query.getResultList();
```

But this isn't working.

So can anyone please help with this, i am struggling with JPA.

The error it shows is:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 
(near line 1, column 15 
[SELECT i FROM (SELECT q FROM com.verisk.backuptracker.model.BtBackupMainStatus q ORDER BY q.dates DESC) i WHERE ROWNUM <= :rownum AND i.flag = :flag]
```

Thanks in advance,

Anish

Comment: Can you share the error message that you are getting? Also, you seem to have a typo in your JPA code (or posting): `q.setParameter("flag", 1);*/`

Comment: Hi, can you write what is the error? Also, i think you copied wrong piece of code, query(which is a string) can not have method getResultList.

Comment: Can you post all code about how you create query and how you add parameter to that.

Comment: you can't have a subquery in the FROM clause in JPQL. You also don't use ROWNUM in JPQL, instead using MaxResults/FirstResult to select the range

Comment: Oh sorry everyone I missed few codes there. Now i have updated the code. Thanks

Comment: so you have a subquery for no benefit. Just remove the subquery, remove the ROWNUM (which all JPQL docs will tell you IS NOT A KEYWORD), and then set maxResults as 5.

Comment: @gvenzl Also i have posted the error it shows. Thanks

Comment: @Periklis Also i have posted the error it shows. Thanks

Comment: @NeilStockon can you please write the query? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ANY JPQL reference would say, use the keywords that are present in JPQL and don't invent your own (because you wouldn't do that in Java so why in a query language?!). Since you don't present classes, then we have to guess what fields are

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM BtBackupMainStatus s WHERE s.flag = :flag ORDER BY s.dates DESC");
q.setParameter("flag", someValue);
q.setMaxResults(5);
List<BtBackupMainStatus> results = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: I have tried this previously but it doesn't give my result. The query works but doesn't give the right output. The above query selects any top 5 rows from table and then order by dates among them 5 rows. But i need to select the latest 5 dates rows.

Comment: The query I post does the "ORDER BY" BEFORE any "limit" of rows (on the JPA implementation + database I use). If you have a problem with the generated SQL with your JPA implementation then I suggest that you bother to look at the LOG for the SQL it is using for this JPQL.

Comment: I got it right from the above code. I was doing a bit wrong coding with it. Now i got it right. Thanks a lot @NeilStockton. You have saved me a lot of time. :)

Answer (score -1):

we cannot do it like this because (SELECT q FROM BtBackupMainStatus q) can not handled as Entity. HQL only works with pojos(Entity) which is mapped with hibernate. so we can use sub-queries in where conditions or in co-related 
sub-queries.